# CryptEncrypt does not encrypt whole text

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, cryptography, wincrypt

I am trying to encrypt a text message with wincrypt. My code is however unpredictable. It doesn't encrypt/decrypt the whole plaintext but only a part of it. If i change the length of password (for example to "password123") it encrypts/decrypts a different amount of characters. Here is my code.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
 const char* passw = "password12";
 const char* toencrypt = "consectetur adipiscing elit. In tellus nisl,   sodales non arcu quis, sagittis maximus orci cras amet.";

 HCRYPTPROV hProv;
 HCRYPTHASH hHash;
 HCRYPTKEY hKey;
 DWORD todwSize = (DWORD)strlen(toencrypt);
 PBYTE pBuffer;

 CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_DELETEKEYSET);
 CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);

 CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash);
 CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)passw, strlen(passw), 0);
 CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_RC4, hHash, 0, &hKey);

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------

 CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, NULL, &todwSize, todwSize);

 pBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(todwSize);
 strcpy((char*)pBuffer, toencrypt);

 CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, pBuffer, &todwSize, todwSize);
 PBYTE pBreturn = pBuffer;
 const char* message =  (const char*)pBreturn;
 printf("%s", message); 

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------

 DWORD dwSize = (DWORD)strlen(message);
 PBYTE depBuffer;


 depBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(1460);
 strcpy((char*)depBuffer, message);



 CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, depBuffer, &dwSize);



 CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
 CryptDestroyHash(hHash);

 CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
 if(GetLastError() != 0)
 {
   printf("%d", GetLastError());
 }
 PBYTE depBreturn = depBuffer;
 printf("%s", (const char*)depBreturn);
 printf("\n%d", strlen(message)); 
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: The first call to `CryptEncrypt` is changing the value of `todwSize` to be the size of the encrypted data, but you then pass it to the second call as both the size of the plaintext *and* the size of the buffer.  Those are two different values, you will need two different variables.

Comment: your main error in `strlen(message);` and `strcpy((char*)depBuffer, message);` - `message` is not 0 terminating string but bianry data wich can containing 0 bytes. you already have len of it `todwSize`

Comment: when you use `CryptAcquireContext` with *NULL* name and not private/public keys - need use `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` and call ` `CryptAcquireContext` only once. of course you not check any functions result and not free resources

Comment: Yeah that was my error, thanks guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

think your code encrypt ok, but fail decrypt whole message because you use wrong length in call `CryptDecrypt`

your main error is `DWORD dwSize = (DWORD)strlen(message);` and `strcpy((char*)depBuffer, message);` but message is encrypted buffer, not 0 terminate ansi string. so you can not use `strlen` or `strcpy` on encrypted data - you have the encrypted data length returned by `CryptEncrypt` : `todwSize` - so you and must use with `memcpy` if you need copy encrypted buffer and pass `todwSize` as is to `CryptDecrypt`

also how noted `Harry Johnston` you incorrect use plain data/buffer size in call `CryptEncrypt`.

must be `CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, NULL, &(needSize = todwSize), 0)` on first call (last parameter to `CryptEncrypt` *dwBufLen* must be 0 because you use *NULL* as buffer, and need use another variable `DWORD needSize` for get size of encrypted buffer and not overwrite size of plain text buffer (`todwSize`) then allocated `needSize` buffer, copy to it `todSize` and call `CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, pBuffer, &todwSize, needSize)`. but however for RC4 the encrypted and plain text size always equal. so `needSize == todSize` always in case RC4

also you need call `CryptAcquireContext` only once with flag `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` in your case. and always need check function result. so test code can be like this

```
int main()
{
    const char* passw = "password12";
    const char* toencrypt = "consectetur adipiscing elit. In tellus nisl,   sodales non arcu quis, sagittis maximus orci cras amet.";

    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    DWORD todwSize = (DWORD)strlen(toencrypt), needSize;
    PBYTE pBuffer;

    if (CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        if (CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
        {
            if (CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)passw, (DWORD)strlen(passw), 0) &&
                CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_RC4, hHash, 0, &hKey))
            {
                if (CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, NULL, &(needSize = todwSize), 0))
                {
                    memcpy(pBuffer = (BYTE *)_alloca(needSize), toencrypt, todwSize);

                    if (CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, pBuffer, &todwSize, needSize))
                    {
                        if (CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, pBuffer, &todwSize))
                        {
                            if (memcmp(pBuffer, toencrypt, strlen(toencrypt)))
                            {
                                __debugbreak();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
            }
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        }
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```